# django, compressor and foundation scss

Tags: django, sass, zurb-foundation

Hi I am trying to integrate foundation scss into django using django-compressor's precompiler, the project looks like this:

```
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── config.rb
│   ├── humans.txt
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── javascripts
│   │   ├── foundation
│   │   │   ├── foundation.alerts.js
│   │   │   ├── foundation.clearing.js
│   │   │   ├── foundation.cookie.js
│   │   │   ├── foundation.dropdown.js
│   │   │   ├── foundation.forms.js
│   │   │   ├── foundation.joyride.js
│   │   │   ├── foundation.js
│   │   │   ├── foundation.magellan.js
│   │   │   ├── foundation.orbit.js
│   │   │   ├── foundation.placeholder.js
│   │   │   ├── foundation.reveal.js
│   │   │   ├── foundation.section.js
│   │   │   ├── foundation.tooltips.js
│   │   │   └── foundation.topbar.js
│   │   └── vendor
│   │       ├── custom.modernizr.js
│   │       ├── jquery.js
│   │       └── zepto.js
│   ├── MIT-LICENSE.txt
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── sass
│   │   ├── app.scss
│   │   ├── normalize.scss
│   │   └── _settings.scss
│   └── stylesheets
│       ├── app.css
│       └── normalize.css
├── templates
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── 500.html
│   ├── admin
│   │   └── base_site.html
│   └── base.html
└── weddings
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── local_settings.py
    ├── local_settings.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── settings.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.pyc
    └── wsgi.py
```

and the precompiler looks like this in settings.py

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'sass --scss --compass {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

And when I run it with nginx + uwsgi, I get the following error:

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/foundation-global.
              Load paths:
                /etc/uwsgi/vassals
                /etc/uwsgi/vassals/sass
                /srv/www/weddings/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
                /srv/www/weddings/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
                Compass::SpriteImporter
                /srv/www/weddings/gems/bourbon-3.1.1/app/assets/stylesheets
                /srv/www/weddings/gems/bourbon-3.1.1/app/assets/stylesheets
        on line 2 of /srv/www/weddings/weddings/static/sass/_settings.scss
        from line 2 of /srv/www/weddings/weddings/static/sass/app.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

I suspect it's not reading the config.rb or the settings in config.rb is wrong:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have a `config.rb` file, you have a Compass project.

Compass projects are supposed to be compiled with the `compass` command line tool, not `sass` command line tool.

As you have already discovered, compilation should be launched from insie the project folder. But it's a bad idea to hardcode the path into settings.py as it makes your project unportable.

Instead of a hardcoded path, you should use `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` to discover current script's path. To change the folder relative to `settings.py`, use `os.path.join()` like this (adjust as necessary, you can use `..`):

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "static")
```

Also, you may already have `PROJECT_DIR` var in your `settings.py`. Use it to make this line cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared things a bit, regarding your recommendation for hardcoded path I am actually using what you recommended `('text/x-scss', 'cd {0}/static && sass --scss --compass --require bourbon.rb {{infile}} {{outfile}}'.format(PROJECT_ROOT)),` I thought that showing the actual path would be more readable here.

Answer (score 1):

A little improvement to @James Lin

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    # ('text/x-scss', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'),
    # ('text/x-scss', 'sass --scss {infile} {outfile}'),
    ('text/x-scss', 'sass --scss --compass {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My current work around is to run the sass command in the folder where ocnfig.rb is located

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'cd /srv/www/project/name/static && sass --scss --compass {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```